# How to interpret ומשביע לכל חי רצון

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, tehilim-psalms

The possuk said multiple times a day in ashrei (psalms 145:16) says

> פותח את ידיך ומשביע לכל חי רצון

Every so often, I see people who are utterly destitute come and ask for money in local shuls. I find it hard to believe that his רצון is satiated.

So I asking how to interpret this possuk - either you find a different explanation or tell me that my understanding of the world is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: possibly (tangentially) related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/i-never-saw-a-tzaddik-be-abandoned-how-do-we-understand-this

Comment: Rabbenu Avraham ben HaRambam ben HaRambam writes in HaMaspik L'ovdey Hashem (Wincellberg translation page 277): when it says, "All look to you" (Tehillim 104:27); "The eyes of all look to you" (ibid 145:15) it means "most". || (Although he is using this to answer the question that not everybody has faith in God, as the verse implies, by extension, it ought to obviate your question.

Comment: Commentless downvote?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't see how this is a duplicate and I recommend reopening. The other question is explicitly only about animals. This one is seemingly only about humans.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99510/reconciling-%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%aa%d7%97-%d7%90%d7%aa-%d7%99%d7%93%d7%9a-and-knowing-people-are-starving