# Nothing missing in the world?

Tags: blessing, tractate-brachot, trees

The Shulchan Aruch OC (226:1) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.226.1?lang=bi) that

> בא"י אמ"ה **שלא חיסר בעולמו כלום** וברא בו בריות טובות ואילנות טובות
> ליהנות בהם בני אדם -  "Blessed Are you....who has **not left anything**
> **lacking in the world** and who has created in in good creations and good
> trees from which people can benefit."

How can we say there is *nothing* lacking in the world (we don't have a Beis Hamikdash, there seems to be tragedies, etc.) and why do we specifically mention the perfection of this world in this particular blessing about the spring?

Comment: All *berachos* tend towards the perfect state?

Comment: I think the bracha just refers to the diversity of G-d's creations, not the state of society.

Comment: Philosophically related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99510/15256

Comment: "Left anything lacking" is a bit of a mistranslation. It would be more accurately translated as "left anything out" - that subtle difference justifies the answer @user27154 wrote.

Comment: My approach to blessings is to see them apriori as **educational rather than informative**, i.g. they are meant to develop kindness, thankfulness, appreciation, rather than to properly describe reality. You might say to your kids "what a beautiful day", ignoring the fact that some people in Chile might be freezing to death, or others are caught in a dreadful tornado.

Answer (score 1):

I think that שלא חיסר Is that no concepts are missing, meaning everything was included in the creation (even the beis hamikdash, and even tragedies ר"ל.)
My humble opinion